# Stuck at Logo, Download Mode doesn't appear, Vol buttons don't work in Recovery mode

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, stock-rom

I currently own a Samsung Galaxy 3 gt i9305 which was network locked by EE. To make it work on GiffGaff I wanted to unlock it.

Current Android version - v4.4.4 (rooted)

I found out that Service mode in v4.4.4 could not be used to unlock the SIM Network. And that I had to downgrade to 4.1.1 to do so.

I was unable to boot into Download mode using hardware keys. They just didn't work and always booted into OS. So I used a on-phone app to boot me in Download mode - It worked!

I used Odin v3.11 to copy the .tar which was used by other users on the forum and seemed to work well for them for the same device. Odin passed! Device rebooted.

Since then, it has been stuck on Samsung logo. Upon further research, I found that I needed to clear the Cache from recovery console, but Volume keys are not working for some reason in the Android Recovery Console 3e. I read on forums that at times they dont highlight and I should use volume keys, assume highlight and use power key to make my selection. Did not work!

Would appreciate any help in reviving the device!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve this problem without using a jig.

I bought a USB jig for the device and forced it to enable Download mode. Odin did rest of the job.